# Updating last accessed time when separating Commands and Queries

Tags: cqrs

Consider a function: IsWalletValid(walletID). It returns true if the walletID exists in the database, and updates a 'last_accessed_time' field.

A task runs periodically to remove any wallets that have not been accessed for a set period of time.

Seems like an easy solution for what we want to do, but IsWalletValid() has a side effect because it writes to the database.

Should we add an additional 'UpdateLastAccessedTime(walletID)' function? Everytime we call IsWalletValid() we will also need to remember to call UpdateLastAccessedTime(walletID).

Comment: Why do you need to update the `last_accessed_time` field?

Comment: If noone accessed a wallet for a few days it is no longer needed and can be deleted.

Comment: CQRS works best with Event Sourcing, because otherwise it becomes really difficult to rebuild secondary (persistent) stores. With Event Sourcing, you never delete anything, so if you want to delete the wallet, I'm wondering if CQRS is the right architecture..?

Comment: There's something I'm missing from your description of the problem: Why does the user need to check whether his own wallet is valid?  If you could describe the problem more in business terms instead of the implementation, it would be easier to give an answer.

Comment: this is an interesting problem, by virtue of someone looking at a piece of data, it changes the system. Maybe you should revisit the requirement. It sounds like you're reimplemting an LRU cache if some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Do verifying that a wallet is valid and updating it's `last_accessed_time` field need to be transactionally consistent (ACID)? You could use eventual consistency here:

The method `IsWalletValid` publishes an `WalletAccessed` event, then an event handler updates `last_accessed_time` asynchronously.

Comment: I disagree strongly with this answer (and I believe most CQRS adherents would agree with me): A query should *never* publish an event.  Only commands publish events.

Comment: yes i agree in this instance, the query side should never mutate the system ie raise events.

Comment: @JoshKodroff Why not? An event indicates that something _interesting_ has happened in your system, it doesn't matter if it's a state change (domain event), an email sent (integration event) or even a query executed (infrastructure, or in this specific case, domain event). You're wrong about commands: commands don't publish events, commands **change** aggregate state. The aggregate is responsible for publishing events. If `IsWalletValid` has a side effect, I prefer to explicitly model it as an event than updating the domain in the read side.

Comment: @boz publishing an event **never** mutates the system. Only commands change aggregate state.

Comment: @boz Luiz' comment is correct.  Luiz, I did not mean to imply that the command itself published events.  *Evecuting* the command publishes events.  The concept of an "aggregate" isn't even necessary - I just think of it as a command handler.  In order to keep things semantically consistent, I would just execute a command when the query is issued, something like `MarkWalletTouched`, but I guess it's not the end of the world if you raise an event when a query is executed.

Comment: @LuizDamim, can you edit the answer so I can remove my downvote?

Comment: Its not a strict rule that domain aggregate publish events, thats an implentation detail. It is a strict rule that te read side of the system should be idempotent and SAFE. raising an event from the read side is destructive or unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

if `last_accessed_time` is not accessed by domain logic to make decisions on any write handling this could just be a facet of the read only projection. Seems like this is the same concern as other more verbose read audit concerns. Just because data is being written and maintained doesn't mean that it necessarily needs to be part of the write model of the system. If you did however want to implement this as part of the domain and perhaps stored within the same event store it could be considered a separate auditing context outside of the boundary of the original aggregate being audited.